# Trying to use Cloudrail, keep getting error: Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2

Tags: ios, swift, cloudrail

I am trying use CloudRail in my project but when I `import CloudrailSI` I keep getting this error:

`Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2`

Anyone know why this keeps happening and what I should do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your XCode is not up to date or you have selected the wrong Swift version for your project. This version of CloudRail is compiled for Swift 3.1. You need to match the same version in your iOS project.